# Efficiency of Selection Sort vs. Insertion Sort

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity

I am currently trying to implement both insertion sort and selection sort in python. Both of my implementations work. However, when I time the sorts, the selection sort consistently performs about 1.5 times faster than the insertion sort, even though my implementation of insertion sort makes about half as many comparisons as my implementation of selection sort. I can't seem to find a reason for this.

```
def select_sort(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        minimum, index = None, i
        for j in range(i, len(data)):
            if minimum is None:
                minimum = data[j]
            if data[j] < minimum:
                minimum = data[j]
                index = j
        data[i], data[index] = data[index], data[i]
    return data

def insert_sort(data):
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        for j in range(i, 0, -1):
            if data[j] >= data[j - 1]:
                break
            data[j], data[j - 1] = data[j - 1], data[j]
    return data

def time_sort(S):
    elapsed = []

    start = time()
    insert_sort(copy(S))
    elapsed.append(time() - start)

    start = time()
    select_sort(copy(S))
    elapsed.append(time() - start)

    return elapsed
```

Comment: Using `xrange` instead of `range` would help as `range` instantiates a new list. You could also store `len(sort)` in a variable which would reduce function calls.

Comment: Yes, but I think both my algorithms use range more or less an equal number of times.

Comment: It probably makes a difference what the dataset is that you are trying to sort. Have you tried this on several datasets?

Comment: Nathan is probably pointing you in the right direction. Insertion sort does well on partially-ordered data.

Comment: Yes. I have a piece of code that generates 100 random numbers between 0 and 1 and executes time_sort on it, then averages the results from 1000 different trials. I will try using xrange though and see if I have any luck.

Comment: Both algorithms improved with the use of xrange but insertion did not improve relative to selection, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert_sort` does O(N<sup>2</sup>) swaps, while `select_sort` does N swaps.

The swap is in the outer loop in `select_sort`, but in the inner loop in `insert_sort`.

Comment: How can I reduce the number of swaps in the insertion sort? I don't want to use the python's insert() method because it is O(n).

Comment: That's just how insertion sort is — it does O(N×N) writes to the array. If you improve it enough, eventually you end up with a merge sort, or a heap sort, or a shell sort. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Variants), for example.

Comment: Instead of swapping the value down to its proper place, I tried shifting all the other values and then placing the value in the 'empty' space. Not sure why, but with this implementation it is faster than my selection sort. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens when you increase the size of input?

Comment: When I increase the size of the input eventually selection sort becomes more efficient again. Any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: This is true, but selection sort also does about twice as many comparisons as insertion sort, on average. In most other languages, insertion sort is consistently faster than selection sort, so this phenomenon is specific to Python and can't really be explained by non-implementation-specific facts about the two algorithms.